# How do I merge database Oracle and Postgres into a Select?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, dbeaver

I have DBeaver and 2 DB connections, Oracle and Postgres. I would like to know how do I use the 2 databases in my select?

Comment: If you are trying to use the two different databases in the same SQL statement, you probably can't.  You'd need some way of connecting the actual databases together (something like Oracle Heterogeneous Services to create a database link from Oracle to a non-Oracle database).

Comment: @JustinCave Or use the [Oracle FDW](https://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/) to do it the other way around.

Comment: @Miiih - I'm not sure what question you are asking.  If you have set up all the infrastructure for it, sure, you could create a database link in DBeaver.  But there would be a fair amount of work that the DBA of one or the other database would need to do in order to allow that.

Comment: @JustinCave 
I want to create a link between Postgre and Oracle using DBeaver, to perform a Select and use data from the tables of each database.

I want to know how I do it

Comment: OK.  Do you want to create the database link on the Oracle side using Oracle Heterogenous Services?  Or on the PostgreSQL side using Oracle FDW?  Are you the DBA on both systems?

Comment: [What's Postgre? Something like My?](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)